# Calculating the thousandth prime

Tags: python, primes

The problem asks to calculate the 1000th prime number. I am trying to solve this problem but I am stuck.

There are some guidelines on how to solve the problem.

To help you get started, here is a rough outline of the stages you should probably follow in
writing your code:

1. Initialize some state variables
2. Generate all (odd) integers > 1 as candidates to be prime
3. For each candidate integer, test whether it is prime
4. One easy way to do this is to test whether any other integer > 1 evenly
   divides the candidate with 0 remainder. To do this, you can use modular
   arithmetic, for example, the expression a%b returns the remainder after
   dividing the integer a by the integer b.
5. You might think about which integers you need to check as divisors –
   certainly you don’t need to go beyond the candidate you are checking, buthow much sooner can you stop checking?
6. If the candidate is prime, print out some information so you know where you are
   in the computation, and update the state variables
7. Stop when you reach some appropriate end condition. In formulating this
   condition, don’t forget that your program did not generate the first prime (2).
   Use these ideas to guide the creation of your code.

My attempt so far is this

```
def calculate_thousandth_prime():
    j = 0
    for i in range(3,int(10e6)):
        if i%2 != 0:
            counter = 0
            for k in range(1, i):
                if i%k != 0:
                    counter += 1
            if counter == 0:
                print("This candidate is prime")
                j += 1
        if j == 1001:
            print("The number "+str(i)+" is the thousandth prime")
            break
    return 0

calculate_thousandth_prime()
```

My code gets stuck on `i%k != 0`. I must be doing something wrong... any help?

Comment: It would be quicker to implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and apply it to the list of integers in the range [1, 1.2*1000*log(1000)] (which by the prime number theorem should be enough)

Comment: This has been implemented very often already. An example is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24361/primes-tester-for-speed-performance (in Java) but there are also https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221678/prime-sieve-and-brute-force (C++) and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=prime+python Python implementations

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _My code gets stuck on `i%k != 0`_.  What does "stuck" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes I made:

1. Change your range to add a `2` step to skip even numbers more naturally.
2. Check your inner loop, you need to divide by the values `range(2, i//2)`. Dividing by anything greater than `i//2` will be less than 2.
3. Change your prime check to see if any number in the above range divides. If so, we know the number is false. At that point we can move onto the next number.
4. We want to return when the prime counter is 1000, you were returning the 1001th prime.

```py
def calculate_thousandth_prime():
    prime_counter = 0
    for i in range(3,int(10e6),2):
        prime = True
        for k in range(2, i//2):
            if i % k == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime:
            print(str(i) + " is prime")
            prime_counter += 1
        if prime_counter == 1000:
            print("The number "+str(i)+" is the thousandth prime")
            break
    return i

calculate_thousandth_prime()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

First, you're searching `for k in range(1, i):`. Because every number, including primes, is divisible by 1, you won't find any primes. Try searching `range(2, i)` instead.

Second, you're checking `if i%k != 0:`. You should be checking that `i%k == 0` instead. If `i` is divisible by any number `k`, then the number is *not* prime.

Actually, I found a third issue: You have an off-by-one error. By initializing `j=0`, your code considers the first prime it finds to be the "zeroth" prime. The code will output the thousand-and-first prime, instead of the thousandth prime.

Answer (score 0):

The sieve of Eratosthenes is generally the fastest way for the early primes.  You can adapt it to reach the nth prime.

For example:

```
def nthPrime(N):
    sieve = [1]*(N**2)
    p     = 2
    for _ in range(N):
        while not sieve[p]: p += 1
        sieve[p::p] = [0]*len(sieve[p::p])
    return p

nthPrime(100) # 541
```

The prime list divisor check method is probably easier to write and understand but it is much slower (although for only 1000 primes, this wouldn't make much of a difference):

```
def nthPrime(N):
    primes = [2]
    p = 1
    while len(primes)<N:
        p += 2
        primes += [p]*all(p%d for d in primes)
    return p
```